# Issue with using slidedown jquery

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I am using google visualization tables in my page. For each table element, a select event has been set as following:

```
 google.visualization.events.addListener(core_table_stats, 'select', selectHandler);
```

The handler is as follows, it opens up a new panel depending upon the content of the row selected:

```
 function selectHandler(e){
                var code=data.getValue(core_table_stats.getSelection()[0].row,0);
                var url="index.jsp?no_menu=true&dashboard=byCodeQualifier&messageCode="+code+"&messageQualifier=SYNC_FAIL";
                $('#detailFrame').attr('src', url);
                $('#detailPanel').show('slide',{ direction: 'down' },400);
             }
```

However, the problem I am facing is that the headers of the table core_table_stats in the base page are visible even on the panel that opens up. How do I hide those headers?

Here is the html that is being used.

```
<table width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' valign='center'  width='350'>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="width:300px;margin:auto;">
                 <li class="well well-sm"  style="width:300px;margin:auto;pading:2px;">CP > APP<span class="badge" id="in" style="font-size:large;"></span></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td align='center' valign='center' width='350' colspan='2'>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="width:300px;margin:auto;">
                 <li class="well well-sm"  style="width:300px;margin:auto;pading:2px;">APP> APP2 <span class="badge" id="in" style="font-size:large;"></span></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='275'>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="width:350px;margin:auto;">
                 <li class="well well-sm"  style="width:300px;margin:auto;">Success <span class="badge" id="success-int" style="font-size:large;"></span></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <br/>
               <div class="panel panel-warning" style="width:380px;margin:auto;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #0174DF">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Fallouts</h3>
                    </div>
                    **<div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="core_stats_table"  style="width: 360px;height: 450px;"></div>**
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='325' style="vertical-align:top;">
                <h4>APP1</h4>
                <div id="pass_fail" class="well well-sm" style="width: 280px; height: 200px;"></div>
                <div id="core_stats" class="well well-lg" style="width: 280px; height: 300px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='325' style="vertical-align:top;">
                <h4>Turbo Map</h4>
                <div id="tm_pass_fail" class="well well-sm" style="width: 280px; height: 200px;"></div>
                <div id="tm_stats" class="well well-lg" style="width: 280px; height: 300px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br/>
                <div class="panel panel-warning" style="width:380px;margin:auto;">
                        <div class="panel-heading"  style="background-color: #0174DF">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Fallouts</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="tm_stats_table" style="width: 360px;height: 450px;"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
         <div id='detailPanel' style='padding: 15px;display:none;position:fixed;left:0px;top:100px;height:800px;width:100%;'>
            <a href='#' onclick="$('#detailPanel').hide('slide',{ direction: 'down' },250);return false;">Close</a><br/>
            <iframe id='detailFrame' name='detailFrame' width='100%' height='790'></iframe>
         </div>
```

Any ideas? Please let me know if the problem is not completely understood

Comment: It will be easy for us to debug if we can see it live in a [fiddle](https://jsbin.com).